# How can I get CPU count and total RAM from the OS X command line?

Tags: mac-osx

How can I get CPU count and total RAM from the OS X command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
scorp@antani-mac:~$ hwprefs cpu_count
2
scorp@antani-mac:~$ hwprefs memory_size
4.00 GB
```

Comment: `hwprefs` doesn't seem to be part of the default OS X install (I think it's in Xcode, or maybe the CHUD tools).

Comment: hwprefs: command not found on Mac Os x Lion

Comment: not on Sierra either

Comment: Confirmed, not in Sierra.

Comment: and not on High Sierra too

Answer (score 87):

You can get this from the `system_profiler` tool:

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep "  Memory:"
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep Cores:
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep Processors:
```

or, if you want to go low-level, use `sysctl`:

```
sysctl hw.memsize
sysctl hw.ncpu
```

Or to capture the values in a script (credit: @bleater):

```
mem_size=$(sysctl -n hw.memsize)
cpus_virtual=$(sysctl -n hw.ncpu)
```

btw, there are a bunch of other interesting things you can get from `sysctl`.  Try:

```
sysctl -a | grep cpu
```

to see a few of them

Comment: +1: The sysctl method works on Mountain Lion.

Comment: To capture the output of sysctl in a script, use the -n option, e.g. sh/bash script:
    CPUS_VIRTUAL=\`sysctl -n hw.ncpu\`

Comment: +1: systemctl works best on 10.11.x

Comment: Thank you. By the way, output of `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType` is human-readable, so I would suggest against piping it to grep.

Comment: Fun fact: `sysctl` is available from the terminal in recovery mode, while many other tools are not (a coworker needed to know how much ram was in a laptop that is locked with file vault)

Comment: Great answer. Sidenote: I definitely LOL'd when I added the `-h` flag to the `sysctl` command expecting to give me "human‑readable" output. It simply added commas… lol Which I guess works fine! I just expected KB, MB, GB, etc. to show up.

Then again, it should probably be GB in the vast majority of cases… The trouble comes when counting digits to learn the order of magnitude of GBs you have I guess.

Answer (score 29):

The following works in OS X Lion:

```
$ /usr/sbin/system_profiler SPHardwareDataType

Hardware:

    Hardware Overview:

      Model Name: iMac
      Model Identifier: iMac7,1
      Processor Name: Intel Core 2 Duo
      Processor Speed: 2.4 GHz
      Number of Processors: 1
      Total Number of Cores: 2
      L2 Cache: 4 MB
      Memory: 4 GB
      Bus Speed: 800 MHz
```

Comment: This was the most useful one for me since I got everything I was looking for from one command, and works on the recovery terminal for Yosemite (10.10).

Comment: Very nice! This is the answer.

Comment: Note that `/usr/sbin/` is usually in `$PATH`.

Comment: This still works as of Catalina, and it's wicked fast, unlike some other options.